# Susy Gutter Width defaults to 1em

Tags: drupal-7, sass, drupal-theming, susy-compass

I'm using Susy within the Omega 4 Drupal frame work and have been having trouble getting the gutter width to change from the default of 1em.

What is really odd is that the background grid responds changes to the gutter width but the elements on the page that are using span-columns keep the 1em gutter width. The compiler as well isn't throwing up any errors.

My susy grid settings are below. I've cross posted this as well to the Drupal Omega page as well. Thanks

```
 // Set consistent vertical and horizontal spacing units.
$vert-spacing-unit: 20px;
$horz-spacing-unit: 2em;

// Define Susy grid variables mobile first.
$total-columns: 4;
$column-width: 4em;
$gutter-width: $horz-spacing-unit;
$grid-padding: 5px;

$container-style: magic;
$container-width: 1900px;
```

Comment: Since you are using magic grids, the output is not actually in `ems`, but in `%` — in your case a % of the `1900px` container you have established. But changing `$gutter-width` should still change the size of gutters relative to the size of columns. Can you show a demo, or more code? It's hard to know what you are seeing from the settings alone.

Comment: @EricMeyer http://dev.adventuretasmania.com.au/activity/franklin-river-rafting

Do a search in dev tools for .views-field-nothing

Comment: I see the problem, but without more samples from your scss, it's not possible to figure out why. How are you setting up the grid-background breakpoints, and how are you setting up the element breakpoints? Are they in different places, or being handled differently in any way?

Comment: @EricMeyer finally figured out out after one of those oh damn moments. The variable file with the susy settings wasn't being picked up properly and so wasn't sharing settings with other components files.

Layouts worked due to having their own declared values in their scss sheets.

Comment: \o/ - glad to hear it.